# Mailchimpp inline responsive form

Tags: html, css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, mailchimp

I am looking in embbeding mailchimp form into a wordpress theme based on bootstrap 3 as a inline form.

I tried using form-inline class but cant get the form to act responsive as a rest of the website.

Can someone help me with this?

My Code:

```
<form class="form-inline col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-12">
            <!-- Begin MailChimp Signup Form -->
                <link href="//cdn-images.mailchimp.com/embedcode/classic-081711.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
                <div id="mc_embed_signup">
                <form action="//myusername.us4.list-manage.com/subscribe/post?u=696bfb5fa3805b0c57f648cfe&amp;id=91164a5f77" method="post" id="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" name="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" class="validate" target="_blank" novalidate>
                    <div id="mc_embed_signup_scroll">

                <!-- <div class="indicates-required"><span class="asterisk">*</span> indicates required</div> -->
                <div class="mc-field-group">
                    <label class="sr-only" for="mce-NAME">Your name</label>
                    <input type="text" value="" name="NAME" class="required" id="mce-NAME" placeholder="Your name">
                </div>
                <div class="mc-field-group">
                    <label class="sr-only" for="mce-EMAIL">Email Address</label>
                    <input type="email" value="" name="EMAIL" class="required email" id="mce-EMAIL" placeholder="Your best email">
                </div>
                    <div id="mce-responses" class="clear">
                        <div class="response" id="mce-error-response" style="display:none"></div>
                        <div class="response" id="mce-success-response" style="display:none"></div>
                    </div>    <!-- real people should not fill this in and expect good things - do not remove this or risk form bot signups-->
                    <div style="position: absolute; left: -5000px;"><input type="text" name="b_696bfb5fa3805b0c57f648cfe_91164a5f77" tabindex="-1" value=""></div>
                    <button type="submit" value="Subscribe" name="subscribe" id="mc-embedded-subscribe" class="btn btn-default">Yes, I want My Ex Back!</button>
                    </div>
                </form>
                </div>

            <!--End mc_embed_signup-->
        </form>
```

Comment: The code you've postet acts responsive, see it at http://jsfiddle.net/Kage/1ahcavto/

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the following to your CSS file.

```
  .form-inline{width:100%}
  .form-inline input{width:100%;border:1px solid #000;padding:.5em 1em}
```